# How can I easily get a reference to a value after it has been moved into a tuple-type enum variant?

Tags: rust

I want to move a value into a tuple-type enum variant and obtain a reference to the value after it has been moved. I see how this is possible with an `if let` statement, but this seems like this should be unnecessary when the particular variant is known statically.

**Is there any way to get the reference to the moved value without requiring an `if let` or `match`?**

This code block is a simple illustration of my question (see below for a more challenging case):

```rust
enum Transport {
    Car(u32),      // horsepower
    Horse(String), // name
}

fn do_something(x: &String) {
    println!(x);
}

fn main() {
    // Can I avoid needing this if, which is clearly redundant?
    if let Transport::Horse(ref name) = Transport::Horse("daisy".into()) {
        do_something(name);
    }
    else {
        // Can never happen
    }

    // I tried the following, it gives:
    //     "error[E0005]: refutable pattern in local binding: `Car(_)` not covered"
    let Transport::Horse(ref name) = Transport::Horse("daisy".into());
}
```

It is easy to find ways to side-step the issue in the above code, since there are no real interface requirements. Consider instead the following example, where I am building a simple API for building trees (where each node can have `n` children). Nodes have an `add_child_node` method returning a reference to the node that was added, to allow chaining of calls to quickly build deep trees. (It is debatable whether this is a good API, but that is irrelevant to the question). `add_child_node` must return a mutable reference to the contents of an enum variant. Is the `if let` required in this example (without changing the API)?

```
struct Node {
    children: Vec<Child>,
    // ...
}

enum Child {
    Node(Node),
    Leaf
}

impl Node {
    fn add_child_node(&mut self, node: Node) -> &mut Node {
        self.children.push(Child::Node(node));

        // It seems like this if should be unnecessary
        if let Some(&mut Child::Node(ref mut x)) = self.children.last() {
            return x;
        }

        // Required to compile, since we must return something
        unreachable!();
    }

    fn add_child_leaf(&mut self) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can use `unreachable!()` for the `else` case, and it's usually clear even without message/comment what's going on. The compiler is also very likely to optimize the check away.

Comment: @HugoBurd Nice. How does this help to get rid of the `if let` constructs to call `do_something()` directly on the `enum` variants?

Answer (score 0):

**If the variants have the same type** you can implement `AsRef` and use the Transport as a `&str`:

```rust
enum Transport {
    Car(String),
    Horse(String),
}

fn do_something<S: AsRef<str>>(x: &S) {
    println!("{}", x.as_ref());
}

impl AsRef<str> for Transport {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &str {
        match self {
            Transport::Car(s) => s,
            Transport::Horse(s) => s,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let transport = Transport::Horse("daisy".into());
    do_something(&transport)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a679def13845ef15f6f5fa1187178060)

Otherwise you need to use a `let if` binding as you are doing. **No need to use an else clause if you don't want to**:

```rust
if let Transport::Horse(ref name) = Transport::Horse("daisy".into()) {
    do_something(name);
}
```

Comment: This works for my particular example where both variants have the same type, but I am more interested in the general case where they may have different types. I will edit to clarify.

Comment: no problem, covered both cases now @HugoBurd

Answer (score 0):

define `From<Transport> for String`:

```
…

impl From<Transport> for String {
    fn from(t: Transport) -> String {
        match t {
            Transport::Car(value)  => value.to_string(),
            Transport::Horse(name) => name,
        }
    }
}

fn do_something(x: Transport) {
    println!("{}", String::from(x));
}


fn main() {
    let horse = Transport::Horse("daisy".to_string());
    let car = Transport::Car(150);
    do_something(horse);
    do_something(car);
}
```

Comment: See updated example in question, I have clarified that the enum variants do not necessarily have the same type

Comment: See it. All rust std types have `to_string()` defined. For other types define `From<T> for String`.

Comment: This removes the redundant `if let` in my example, but does not answer the question. I have added another example which gives a more complete illustration of the issue.

Comment: `if let Some(&mut Child::Node(ref mut x)) = self.children.last()` or a `match` is necessary, as `last()` returns an `Option`.
Again You can define `impl From<Node> for TypeOfX`.